# Get all gameobjects that begin with a certain string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to collect all gameObjects that begin with certain string or a tag. For example, the string/tag is "Sub-". I would like to add all of them to my list. How do I achieve this?

```
public List<GameObject> subs = new List<GameObject>();

private void Start(){
   foreach(GameObject subGroup in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sub-")) {
 
             subs.Add(subGroup);
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `Linq` you could do something like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

// get all Transform components of the scene
// pass in true to include inactive ones
var all = FindObjectsOfType<Transform>(true);

// Filter and only keep the ones whee the name starts with your string
subs = all.Where(obj => obj.name.StartsWith(nameOfObj)).ToList();
// Or use a certain tag
subs = all.Where(obj => obj.CompareTag(nameOfObj)).ToList();
// or check if the tag starts with your string
subs = all.Where(obj => obj.tag.StartsWith(nameOfObj)).ToList();
```

see [`Object.FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) and [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where)

Comment: Hey thank you. I will use this for a string. how can I do the same for tag? And will it also consider inactive objects?

Comment: @Roy see comments and update ;)